# Prove inequality: $\sum \frac{a^4}{a^3+b^3} \ge \frac{a+b+c}{2}$

Tags: inequality

> Prove inequality with $a,b,c >0$ $$\frac{a^4}{a^3+b^3} +
>  \frac{b^4}{b^3+c^3}+\frac{c^4}{c^3+a^3} \ge \frac{a+b+c}{2}$$

I tried the inequality: $\sum \frac {a^4+b^4}{a^3+b^3} \ge \sum \frac{a+b}2=a+b+c$, but seem like it doesn't help

Comment: Without loss of generality you may assume that $a=1$ and thus reduce to a two-variables problem.

Comment: @Eckhard: How can you assume that? Generality is lost there, I suppose.

Comment: @Inceptio: you suppose wrong. For every $\lambda>0$, the inequality is satisfied for a triple $(a,b,c)$ if and only if is satisfied for any triple $(\lambda a,\lambda b,\lambda c)$, because both sides of the inequality scale linearly in $\lambda$. In particular, you may take $\lambda=a^{-1}$ to reduce to the case $a=1$.

Comment: To reduce it to 2 variables, put $b=k_1a$ and $c=k_2a$. You can even assume $k_1 \leq k_2$

Comment: @Eckhard: Right. I supposed wrong.

Comment: Since it is not symmetric, I think you probably need to discuss the order of the variables. I got $\sum(a^7b^3+a^3b^7) +\sum a^6(b^4-c^4) - abc\sum(a^5b^2+a^2b^5)$, the only problem is the asymmetric term, if you can prove at any time one of these three should be right, $\sum a^7b^3\ge \sum a^6c^4$ or $\sum a^3b^7\ge \sum a^6c^4$ or $\sum a^6b^4 \ge\sum a^6c^4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an extensive discussion of this inequality here: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=51&t=23113

I like  the sum of squares method the best:

\begin{align}
& \sum_{cyc}{\frac{a^4}{a^3+b^3}}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}{a} \\
& =\frac{(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2(ab+ac+bc)^2}{4(a^3+b^3)(b^3+c^3)(c^3+a^3)} \\
& +\sum_{cyc}{\frac{c^2(b-c)^2(2c^3(a^3+b^3)+c^2a^2(a+b)^2+2ca^4b+a^4(a^2+b^2))}{4(a^3+b^3)(b^3+c^3)(c^3+a^3)}} \\
& \geq 0
\end{align}